# 'List' type not available in C# SharePoint Web Part development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, sharepoint, web-parts

I am currently working with Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 3.5 to develop SharePoint Web Parts. My Microsoft development experience is mostly .NET 4.5, MVC4 and Visual Studio 2012.

I'm wondering, why is it that there is no List type (`List<int>, List<string>, List<ObjectName>,` etc) in C# in this environment? I've googled the issue all over the place and can't find a thing. Is there an alternative that I should be using instead? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `using System.Collections.Generic` in your source code file(s).